# Converting Mercurial repo to Git. Large .git folder, but no code files

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I'm fairly inexperienced with Git. I just used the hg-git extension to convert a Mercurial repo with 100+ branches by pushing it to a new local git repo. The local git repo has a 300mb .git folder, which is somewhat consistent with the size of the original hg repo, but the git repo contains no actual code files. Obviously the files/changesets are in the .git folder, but I don't know how to "extract" them for lack of better term to the repo.

I also have a remote blank git repo on Bitbucket, when I try to git push to that nothing happens.

Comment: Use `git` commands to look into the repository. `git status`, `git log`, `git branch -a`…

Comment: In mercurial terms are you looking for a way to update your working folder?